# Await promises in async loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, promise

Why does this code snippet doesn't work as expected, so that `console.debug(images)` is called before the object is filled with data? I want the two loops to run parallel, but `await Promise.all` should wait for the loops to finish. Both the first loop and the second loop should run simultaneously.

```
const images = {
     taskImages: [],
     solutionImages: []
};

await Promise.all(Object.keys(files).map((key) => {
    files[key].map(async (file) => {
        const fileId = getFileId(file.path);
        const result = await storeImage(fileId, file.path);
        if (result) {
            images[key].push(fileId);
            console.debug("Pushed " + key);
        }
    });
}));

console.debug(images);
```

Comment: You have to define the await on a variable. `const promises = await Promise.all([]);`

Comment: @Baruch I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function in the outer `.map()` call doesn't return anything, so `Promise.all` doesn't get any promises to wait for.

The solution is just to wrap the inner `map()` in `Promise.all(...)` and return that:

```
await Promise.all(Object.keys(files).map((key) => {
    return Promise.all(files[key].map(async (file) => {...}));
}));
```

Comment: It works, but does this mean that the outer loop waits for the inner loop to finish? I want the outer loop to start the inner loop and the to continue. So every single loop action should run in an own "thread".

Comment: @Twister21 Only the `await` will stop execution of the function. `Promise.all` just returns a new promise that collects all the promises you give it.

Comment: @Twister21 -  There is only one Javascript "thread" so thinking of each invocation of the loop running in its own thread is not a good way to think about it..  `await` suspends execution of an `async` function until the promise resolves and then lets other events get processed while its waiting for that promise to resolve so it can then resume execution of that function.  When that promise resolves, it has to then get back in line in the event queue and wait until whatever else was running at the time to finish before it gets its turn to then resume executing that function.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple solution 1:**

[image]

[image]

**Solution 2:**

you also can use

npm async library

[Link](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel)

```
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    // results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```

Comment: Why bother with obsolete third-party solution like async library when there are native ones that do same thing?

Comment: Code should be posted as text, properly formatted as code, not as images.  Images cannot be searched, cannot be copied and pasted from, etc... and are a lot less useful than properly formatted text.

Comment: I agree with estus.  Promises are the present and future of Javascript for managing asynchronous operations, not the Async library.  We should be teaching newbies only promises, `await` and `async`, not traditional callbacks covered up with the Async library.